# Parsing string to protobuf enum with no case-sensitivy

Tags: c++, parsing, enums, protocol-buffers

With C++ API, Enum_Parse() seems to be case sensitive, is there way to make it ignore case? With the enum definition at the bottom, Enum_Parse accepts "Http", but it rejects "http". I have searched enum related options in the link below, but did not find one about this.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Tcp = 0;
    Http = 1;
    Https = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its possible for you to rename enums to the small case like this -

```
enum MyEnum
{
    tcp = 0;
    http = 1;
    https = 2;
}
```

Then you could convert the input string to the small case first and then use Enum_Parse()